# Using --my_argument `cat some_file` as argument to some command

Tags: command-line, bash, script

I'm running a command with options/parameters based on files. 
So I `cat` the files inside the command. 
However, when there's nothing in the file, this is problematic.

```
mkbootimg --kernel "$SCRIPT_DIR/devices/$DEVICE/kernel/k/arch/arm64/boot/Image" \
--ramdisk boot.img-ramdisk \
--dtb boot.img-dtb \
--cmdline "$(cat boot.img-cmdline)" \
--base `cat boot.img-base` \
--kernel_offset `cat boot.img-kernel_offset` \
--ramdisk_offset `cat boot.img-ramdisk_offset` \
--tags_offset `cat boot.img-tags_offset` \
--dtb_offset `cat boot.img-dtb_offset` \
--os_version `cat boot.img-os_version` \
--os_patch_level `cat boot.img-os_patch_level` \
--pagesize `cat boot.img-pagesize` \
--header_version `cat boot.img-header_version` \
--hashtype `cat boot.img-hashtype` \
--board `cat boot.img-board` \
--ramdisk_offset `cat boot.img-ramdisk_offset` \
-o ../boot.img)
```

For example, if there's nothing in `boot.img-board`
and "0x10000" in `boot.img-ramdisk_offset`, then

```
--board `cat boot.img-board` \
--ramdisk_offset `cat boot.img-ramdisk_offset` \
```

does

```
--board   --ramdisk_offset 0x10000
```

and thus it thinks that the `board` is `--ramdisk_offset`
and then interprets `0x10000` as another argument for `mkbootimg`.

I want to do `--board`
only when there's actually something in `boot.img-board`. 
If there's nothing in the file, I'd like to not pass the argument,
but go ahead any execute the command without it. 
What is the best way to solve this problem?

(The files will never have two or more words in them.)

Comment: I dont think there is 1 best way to do this.  I'd convert that into a script, then check if  $(cat boot.img-cmdline) has something in it - eg by assigning it to a string and comparing the string. If the string is not empty, prepend "--cmdline " to it and put the variable into the command you wrote.

Comment: (1) What do you want to happen if one of the files is empty? Abort the whole command? Skip the option? (2) Don’t you (at least in theory) have the same problem if a file has two or more words in it?

Comment: @Scott if there's nothing on the file I'd like to not pass the argument. And the files will never have 2 words on it

Comment: You know there exist already [script](https://github.com/osm0sis/Android-Image-Kitchen/blob/AIK-Linux/repackimg.sh) for?

Answer (score 2):

Building on [Hannu’s answer](https://superuser.com/a/1708313/150988) and [But what if …?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/286350/23408),
since you have specified [bash](/questions/tagged/bash),

```
args=(
        --kernel "$SCRIPT_DIR/devices/$DEVICE/kernel/k/arch/arm64/boot/Image"
        --ramdisk boot.img-ramdisk
        --dtb boot.img-dtb
        --cmdline "$(cat boot.img-cmdline)"
)
for param in base kernel_offset ramdisk_offset tags_offset dtb_offset os_version \
            os_patch_level pagesize header_version hashtype board ramdisk_offset
do
        f="boot.img-$param"
        if [ "$(wc -w < "$f")" = 1 ]
        then
                args+=("--$param" "$(cat "$f")")
        else
                printf 'Problem with %s.\n' "$f"
        fi
done
args+=(-o ../boot.img)
mkbootimg "${args[@]}"
```

Thank you for naming the files consistently; that made the job easier.

This creates an array called `args`,
and starts it off with the fixed parameters
(`kernel`, `ramdisk`, `dtb` and `cmdline`). 
(If you want to check the content(s) of the `boot.img-cmdline` file,
just augment the script accordingly, or ask for help if you need it.) 
The code then loops through the file-driven parameters. 
If a file contains exactly one word,
the option and the value are added to the array;
otherwise, the parameter is skipped. 
After the loop, we add the `-o` option, and execute the command.

Notes:

- I copied your code fairly faithfully,
  to the point of including `ramdisk_offset` twice,
  even though I suspect that that’s a typo.
- I changed `` `…` `` to the equivalent `$(…)`
  for reasons discussed elsewhere on this site.
- I have written the code to handle only files
  that contain *exactly* one word. 
  If you decide / realize that you might have files with more than one word,
  the code will have to be changed.
- If you want, you can include backslashes on this multi-line construct:

  ```
  args=( \
          --kernel "$SCRIPT_DIR/devices/$DEVICE/kernel/k/arch/arm64/boot/Image" \
          --ramdisk boot.img-ramdisk \
          --dtb boot.img-dtb \
          --cmdline "$(cat boot.img-cmdline)" \
  )
  ```

  but you don’t need to. 
  When the shell sees a `(`,
  it knows that it has to keep reading until it sees the matching `)`.
- Also, if you want, you can put multiple options on one line:

  ```
  args=(--kernel "$SCRIPT_DIR/devices/$DEVICE/kernel/k/arch/arm64/boot/Image"
        --ramdisk boot.img-ramdisk --dtb boot.img-dtb --cmdline "$(cat boot.img-cmdline)")
  ```
- For readability and editability,
  you might want to list the parameters on separate lines:

  ```
  for param in \
          base \
          kernel_offset \
          ramdisk_offset \
          tags_offset \
          dtb_offset \
          os_version \
          os_patch_level \
          pagesize \
          header_version \
          hashtype \
          board \
          ramdisk_offset
  do
          …
  ```
- This must be run in bash.

  - If you’re running your script the clunky way,
    you must say `bash script.sh`. 
    If you say `sh script.sh`, you’re running the default shell (`/bin/sh`),
    which may be POSIX-compliant, but probably isn’t bash,
    and might not support arrays.
  - If you’re running it as an executable script
    (do `chmod +x` and then run it as `./script.sh`),
    you must begin the script with a “shebang” of

    ```
    #!/bin/bash
    ```

    or

    ```
    #!/usr/bin/env bash
    ```

    This must be the first line of the script.

  P.S. Actually, if you can’t use bash, there is an alternative. 
  See [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/286350/23408).

Answer (score 1):

Simplistic answer:

```
if [ $( cat boot.img-board | tr '\n' '\x20' | wc -w ) -gt 0 ] ;then
  # do your thing
else 
  echo "We have no data to process...\b"
fi

# UNTESTED
```

which simply means; check whether there is any "words" inside the file, if yes; launch the process, otherwise just tell about the fact.

The check: Read the file, replace any NEWLINE characters with spaces (put all on one line) and test whether there are anything else than whitespace in the result.

**Understanding Bash, more of the above**:
Go to [www.tldp.org](https://www.tldp.org), find and read the Bash guides.

Comment: but I intended to do this for all arguments, not just for the board one

Comment: Why do you need the ``tr``?

Comment: I have no idea what the file contains, assuring all there is, is on one line, for `wc -w`; now as you noted - that might not be necessary...

Comment: @GuerlandoOCs, you might need to do the above thing for each, building a set of arguments in a variable `arguments="$arguments $(cat argument file)"`, then use them via that variable, as in `command $arguments`

Comment: @Hannu Well, duh. I posted an hour that does that yesterday.

Answer (score 1):

You tagged [bash](/questions/tagged/bash), so I won't hesitate to use Bash-specific syntax.

A reliable way is to build the command (or at least the arguments) as an array. You can add to the array *conditionally*. Example:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

unset arr
arr=(--ramdisk boot.img-ramdisk)
arr+=(--dtb boot.img-dtb)
arr+=(--option 'value    with     spaces')
# etc.

# essence begins
value=$(<boot.img-board)
if [ "$value" ]; then
   arr+=(--board "$value")
fi
# essence ends

arr+=('final argument')
printf '<%s>\n' "${arr[@]}"
```

After building the right array, use `mkbootimg "${arr[@]}"` instead of `printf …`.

Comment: It goes without saying that I had 99% finished writing my answer before I saw yours.

Comment: @Scott I believe you. Even if you started after, your answer would be justified because of this `for param in …` idea.